# How to enable the clock after removing it from the taskbar in XFCE?

Tags: xfce, xubuntu, clock

My clock was off so I decided to remove it, change the settings, and put it back in the right-hand corner on the taskbar, but I can't seem to be able to do that after removing it. I searched in the settings, system and so on, but still couldn't find it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The clock in the xfce panel is one of the panel plugins. [here](http://www.funtoo.org/XFCE_Panel_Plugins) you can see, how to add and configure panel plugins!